# SQL Subqueries - Results with duplicates and would like to see one row only

Tags: sql

I'd like to see 1 row with the most current Entry Date, Status work time stamp and CMPR time stamp.

```
SELECT 
    D.AccountNumber, D.CaseId, D.EntryDate, 
    D.pyStatusWorkTimeStamp, L.CMPR_TIMESTAMP
FROM 
    dispute_archive D 
LEFT JOIN 
    cmpr_letter_archive L ON D.CaseId = L.FULL_CASEID
WHERE 
    D.CaseId = 'D-1000130' 
ORDER BY 
    D.EntryDate, D.pyStatusWorkTimeStamp, L.CMPR_TIMESTAMP ASC
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Hi - please format your code as code so that it is readable. Also, don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text. Show sample data for your source table(s) and the result you want to achieve

Comment: Please state your dbms (`sql server`, `mysql`,`potgresql`,etc)

Comment: In `SQL Server`, you can achieve this by `order by desc` and have `top 1` on select

Comment: Regarding the tag "SQL" if you hover over that tag please read its description: "*Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL*"

Answer (score 0):

A convenient method to arrive at "the most recent" row is to use `row_number() over()` ordering this by a timestamp in descending order so most recent is row number 1.

Now I'm not entirely certain of your requirements but if you want the most recent rows as determined by combinations of `AccountNumber, CaseId` and the `EntryDate` determines "most recent" then this should work:

```
SELECT
      D.AccountNumber
    , D.CaseId
    , D.EntryDate
    , D.pyStatusWorkTimeStamp
    , L.CMPR_TIMESTAMP
FROM (
    SELECT AccountNumber
        , CaseId
        , EntryDate
        , pyStatusWorkTimeStamp
        , row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY AccountNumber, CaseId
            ORDER BY EntryDate DESC
            ) AS rn -- the most recent gets 1
    FROM dispute_archive
    WHERE CaseId = 'D-1000130'
    ) D
LEFT JOIN cmpr_letter_archive L ON D.CaseId = L.FULL_CASEID
WHERE D.rn = 1 -- the most recent
ORDER BY D.EntryDate
    , D.pyStatusWorkTimeStamp
    , L.CMPR_TIMESTAMP ASC
```

nb: You can order by more than one column if needed.g.

```
        , row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY AccountNumber, CaseId
            ORDER BY EntryDate, D.pyStatusWorkTimeStamp DESC
            ) AS rn -- the most recent gets 1
```